# Alternative to SendKeys in InputBox to choose cells with least user input

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I use the SendKeys method, for user-friendliness, with an InputBox, for selecting multiple cells to use for calculations.

I want to avoid having the user hold CTRL while clicking each cell or pressing Shift-F8 to select multiple cells.

I want the InputBox to pop up and to select cells that are not necessarily right next to one another, without having to do anything else.

Here is a sample of what I have.

```
Sub CalculateIt()
    Dim calcRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    SendKeys "+{F8}"
    Set calcRange = Application.InputBox("Select the cells you would like to use.", Type:=8)
    If Err.Number = 424 Then Exit Sub

    Dim stuff As Double
    For Each calcCell in calcRange
        If IsNumeric(calcCell.Value) Then stuff = stuff + calcCell.Value
    Next calcCell

    MsgBox "The Solution: " & Sqr(stuff)
End Sub
```

I want to avoid using the SendKeys method because I've read a lot about it being finicky and fragile, and that it can cause problems. I have run into some scenarios where it doesn't work and I have to hold CTRL or do Shift-F8 anyways.

Comment: instead of using the user select something... can you have them enter the cells information into another spreadsheet, before the script has run, then reference that in your script??

Comment: @ShanayL Thank you. I could but that also introduces more step(s) and the main goal is to make it as simple as possible to select the data. The data will also never be in the same place, nor will it be the same values, so there's no way to automate grabbing the cells. :/ Unfortunately, I think the best way is to just have the user select which cells they want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution... Add a checkbox to the worksheet then go into the Microsoft Excel Objects | ThisWorkbook window and enter the following code. If the checkbox is checked, then whatever formula you'd like executed will be as the user clicks each cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nbrCell As Double
If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then nbrCell = ActiveCell.Value Else nbrCell = 0
If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value + nbrCell
End Sub
```

You can also add a second checkbox to remove selected cells if you're concerned the user might accidentally click on the wrong cell and want that value removed.